# VBA: Use Text Box to Populate List Box on Word User Form - Query excel data base

Tags: database, vba, excel, ms-word, userform

I want to populate a List Box on a Word User Form based on the data entered in a Text Box on the same form. Ideally this would happen in real time (using the change event I think) with each character entered in the Text Box filtering the items that appear in the List Box.

The data source is an Excel "data base" accessed using DAO. The code below works but it enters the entire data base into List Box (based on this - [Link](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/InterDev/FillListBoxFromXLDAO.htm)).

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim NoOfRecords As Long

    'Open the database (Excel File)
    Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\T400\Documents\UserFormListTest.xlsx" _
          , False, False, "Excel 8.0")

    'Retrieve the recordset > Excel Range = "ListBoxData"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ListBoxData")

    ' Determine the number of retrieved records
    With rs
         .MoveLast
            NoOfRecords = .RecordCount
         .MoveFirst
    End With

    ' Set the number of Columns = number of Fields in recordset
    ListBox1.ColumnCount = rs.Fields.Count
    ListBox1.Column = rs.GetRows(NoOfRecords)

        rs.Close
        db.Close

        Set rs = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing

    End Sub
```

How can I filter the data so the List Box is only populated per the Text Box? I was hoping for a simple solution like maybe modifying the `SELECT *` query portion of the code.

Is this possible? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You're on the right track! Add `Where` clause to `Select` statement to be able to filter data.

Comment: Thanks!  I added `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ListBoxData WHERE Name = 'Andy Smith'")` and it returned only this record. Not using the text box yet but encouraging.

Comment: I can't get this to run when I replace the `"Andy Smith"` hard coded in the above comment with a variable. I think its the syntax and have tried several variations with and without  single and double quotes etc. ... any suggestions?

Comment: `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ListBoxData WHERE Name = '" &  theName & "' " )` where `theName` is a variable containing the name you want to search for

Comment: Thank you, that works. I also got it going using using `("SELECT * FROM ListBoxData WHERE Name = " & Chr$(39) & strSearch & Chr$(39))`. Both of these work when the complete field text is used in the search, now I'm trying now to incorporate wildcards so can search based on each character entered in text box but cannot get that going. Tried many variations like `("SELECT * FROM ListBoxData WHERE Name LIKE = " & Chr$(39) & "%" & strSearch & "%" & Chr$(39))` to no avail - often error indicates no record found. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: BTW, I've also tried putting the wildcards in the search string seemed less complicated than putting in the query. So if I typed the letter "a" into the text box, the strSearch variable would return `"%a%"` ... but still could not get working this way.

Comment: EXcel uses Jet database engine. Replace `%` with `*` and this should start working.

Comment: Tried this where "strSearch = ****a**** in  `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ListBoxData WHERE Name LIKE = " & Chr$(39) & strSearch & Chr$(39))` . I get : Run Time Error 3075  Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in query expression 'Name Like = '*a*''

Comment: ugh struggling with this comment editor, the `strSearch = a` with a single * wild card on either side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment to the question, MS Excel uses Jet database engine. So, you have to use wildcards which correspond to that database engine.

So, if you want to develop custom "search/find" functionality, you may add Combobox control on the form with these options: `All`, `StartsWith`, `Contains` and `EndsWith`. A sample code should look like (replace the name of controls to yours):

```
Dim sName As String
Dim sSearchType As String
Dim sQry As String 

sName = TextBox1.Text
sSearchType = ComboBox1.Value

sQry = "SELECT * FROM ListBoxData "
Select Case sSearchType
    Case "All"
        'do nothing; return all records
    Case "StartsWith"
        sQry = sQry & "WHERE Name Like '" & sName & "*'"
    Case "Contains"
        sQry = sQry & "WHERE Name Like '*" & sName & "*'"
    Case "EndWith"
        sQry = sQry & "WHERE Name Like '*" & sName & "'"
End Select

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sQry)
'other stuff
```

More about wildcards, you'll find here:
[Access wildcard character reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1)
[Office: Wildcard Characters used in String Comparisons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440632(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: OK thanks, I will spend some time with this code and reading up as well

Comment: This works! Answer accepted. I'm going to only use your "contains" option - it works great for all and the search results are instantaneous. I still have some kinks to work out as now gives a "No Current Record" error if I enter a character that is not in the field. I expect I can work this out but if any suggestions feel free to offer. This has been painful, thanks for the help.

Comment: You're very welcome ;) Recordset.Count is what your looking for for "No current Record".